# Convert irregular date format to year only in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm working with a dataframe has one date column with irregular date format, ie:

```
          date
0         1991
1         1970
2   1991/01/01
3   1996-01-01
4   1996-06-30
5   1995-12-31
6   1997-01-01
7     1970/1/1
8   1996-01-01
9   1997-01-01
10  1996-01-01
```

How can I extract year only from `date` to get a new column `year` with standard format XXXX, which represents year only.

```
          year
0         1991
1         1970
2         1991
3         1996
4         1996
5         1995
6         1997
7         1970 
8         1996
9         1997
10        1996
```

Use `df.date.unique()`, I get the following output:

```
array([2015, 2008, 2021, 1999, 2001, 2000, 1997, 1995, 1998,
       datetime.datetime(1905, 7, 2, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(1905, 7, 7, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 1, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 1, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 1, 0, 0), '2019', 1992, ...], dtype=object)
```

I use the following code but, year only date have missed from this columns:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce').astype(str).replace("NaT", "")
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.year
# df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period('Y')
```

Anyone could help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In sample data all datetimes are parsed correctly, so added [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html):

```
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce').dt.year
```

Another idea is convert values to strings and use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for integers with length `4`:

```
df['year'] = df['date'].astype(str).str.extract('(\d{4})').astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)
          date  year
0         1991  1991
1         1970  1970
2   1991/01/01  1991
3   1996-01-01  1996
4   1996-06-30  1996
5   1995-12-31  1995
6   1997-01-01  1997
7     1970/1/1  1970
8   1996-01-01  1996
9   1997-01-01  1997
10  1996-01-01  1996
```

Comment: Awsome. One more question, does `to_period('Y')` to extract year exist in Pandas? I know `to_period('M')`

Comment: @ahbon - I think yes, use `df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce').dt.to_period('Y')`

Comment: Get `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer` with your second solution, with first solution, year data from original cell are missed. I have tried, your previously posted solution works fine.